# Using linear combinations with vectors to find c

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I am having a bit of trouble with this question

[13,-15] is a linear combination of [1,5] and [3,c], this is my approach so far

```
[13,-15] = a[1,5] + b[3,c]

 13 = a + 3b
-15 = 5a + bc
```

How do I find of C?

Answer (score 1):

A general method is to do Gaussian elimination: you want that the system
$$
\begin{cases}
a+5b=13\\
3a+cb=-15
\end{cases}
$$
(in the unknowns $a$ and $b$) has a solution. The matrix of the system is
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}
1 & 5 & 13 \\
3 & c & -15
\end{array}\right]
$$
Now, add to the second row the first row multiplied by $-3$:
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}
1 & 5 & 13 \\
0 & c-15 & -54
\end{array}\right]
$$
It's clear from the new form of the system that a solution exists if and only if $c\ne15$.

Indeed, if $c=15$ the second equation is $0=-54$ that has no solution. If $c\ne15$, you can rewrite the system as
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}
1 & 5 & 13 \\
0 & 1 & 54/(15-c)
\end{array}\right]
$$
and you immediately find a solution by adding to the first row the second row multiplied by $-5$:
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}
1 & 0 & (13c+75)/(c-15) \\
0 & 1 & 54/(15-c)
\end{array}\right]
$$